# Run controller function from model in CakePHP 2

Tags: cakephp, model-view-controller, cakephp-2.0

I run some validation functionality in my controllers, who inherit the function like such:

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    protected function security_redirect ($msg) {
        die(json_encode(['sec_error' => $msg]));
    }
```

I call like `$this->security_redirect('bad thing')` from my controllers and all is grand. But now I need to do so from a controller's *model*, and I can't figure out how. Things I've tried:

`$this->security_redirect` as I always do

`parent::security_redirect`

`$this->parent::security_redirect`

Always ends up in error.

Comment: You should scratch that idea, issuing redirects is not a model's concern! I'd suggest that you elaborate about the specific circumstances, and what exactly your controller and model are doing, so that someone could suggest a proper solution for the underlying problem that you're trying to solve.

Comment: Maybe it's a "purity of purpose" concern, but it really isn't a PHP redirect; it just kills the script and my frontend framework checks for 'sec_error'. The frontend is what redirects the user. So I really don't mind that a model function performs this task, it was previously a controller function that I'm just moving into the model.

Comment: I see that, but still, that's absolutely not a model's concern! If you show and explain what your controller and model are doing, then I'm pretty sure that I could suggest you a proper way of handling this.

Comment: My controller is playing an 'event' in a game, which can take in a large number of inputs and has to account for where the player is in the world, if they're locked into another event, etc. In this case, if they're trying to use an item that they don't have. In an effort to clean this controller up, I'm moving this "security check" to the model.

Comment: That sounds rather abstract, some code would really help here. Doing checks on data in your model is fine, especially if it's related to the datasource of the model, but it has no business in modifying the request, it should just return a state with regards to the data. Your controller should evaluate that state and prepare the response accordingly. If you're trying to DRY up things for the controller layer, you could move preparing the response (and even communicating with the model) in for example a component.

Comment: On a related note, you usually shouldn't just die in your application, unless it's some freaky edge case where you have absolutely no other choice. Usually you'd just return a response object if you want to halt further processing.

Comment: It's fine, I understand where you're coming from; it's trivial to return the error message from the model. I just want to run `$this->Event->my_cool_function()` and have it kill the script then and there. No need to get more complex than that; really, I don't even need `security_redirect()` in AppController. It could just exist in bootstrap.php. A lot of what Cake can do is now irrelevant to me as I'm no longer relying on SSR to generate views. I kind of just want to run an AppController function from the model and be done with it, and I respect that it won't work that way, for good reason.